# AWS Multi-docker deploy Essential container in task exited

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm having this problem on deploying my local docker config to AWS:

> ERROR: ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (benj-elasticsearch:
>   benj-nginx:
>   benj-php-fpm: )

The error log:

```
+ RETRY=0
+ initctl start eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20170711-9737-o42dsc
initctl: Job failed to start
+ '[' -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.eb-ecs-start-no-retry ']'
+ warn 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
+ echo 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
+ eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...' --severity WARN
+ RETRY=1
+ sleep 3
+ '[' 1 -gt 1 ']'
+ initctl start eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20170711-9737-o42dsc
initctl: Job failed to start
+ '[' -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.eb-ecs-start-no-retry ']'
+ warn 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
+ echo 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
+ eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...' --severity WARN
+ RETRY=2
+ sleep 3
+ '[' 2 -gt 1 ']'
+ error_exit 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.' 1
+ error 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'
+ echo 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'
Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.
+ eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.' --severity ERROR
+ exit 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/common.sh
+ RETRY=0
+ initctl start eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20170711-9737-o42dsc
initctl: Job failed to start
+ '[' -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.eb-ecs-start-no-retry ']'
+ warn 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
+ echo 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
+ eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...' --severity WARN
+ RETRY=1
+ sleep 3
+ '[' 1 -gt 1 ']'
+ initctl start eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20170711-9737-o42dsc
initctl: Job failed to start
+ '[' -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.eb-ecs-start-no-retry ']'
+ warn 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
+ echo 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
+ eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...' --severity WARN
+ RETRY=2
+ sleep 3
+ '[' 2 -gt 1 ']'
+ error_exit 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.' 1
+ error 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'
+ echo 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'
Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.
+ eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.' --severity ERROR
+ exit 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Some remarks:

So I have my local docker-compose.yml. I ported this to the Dockerrun.aws.js BUT because I use my own container (bensji/php-fpm), I had to deploy that container to the cloud.

These are my files:
Dockerrun.aws.js

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
"volumes": [
  {
    "name": "benj",
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/var/app/current"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "fpmconf",
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/docker/production/php-fpm"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "nginxconf",
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/docker/production/nginx"
    }
  }
],
"containerDefinitions": [
  {
    "name": "benj-nginx",
    "image": "phpdockerio/nginx:latest",
    "essential": true,
    "memory": 128,
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "Container",
        "value": "nginx"
      }
    ],
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 80,
        "containerPort": 80
      }
    ],
    "links": [
      "benj-php-fpm"
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume": "benj",
        "containerPath": "/var/www/benj",
        "readOnly": true
      },
      {
        "sourceVolume": "nginxconf",
        "containerPath": "/usr/local/nginx/conf",
        "readOnly": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "benj-php-fpm",
    "image": "bensji/php-fpm:latest",
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "Container",
        "value": "php-fpm"
      }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "memory": 128,
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume": "benj",
        "containerPath": "/var/www/benj"
      },
      {
        "sourceVolume": "fpmconf",
        "containerPath": "/usr/local/php/etc",
        "readOnly": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "benj-elasticsearch",
    "image": "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0",
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "Container",
        "value": "elasticsearch"
      }
    ],
    "memory": 128,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 9200,
        "containerPort": 9200
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: Any insight into this?  The logs are absolutely horrible!

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @Tiois anyone get the solution?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi After digging in the logs, if I remember correctly, it was a permission problem when copying some files. I'm using AWS EB, and I had to create a ".ebextensions" folder with a "permissions.config" file having YML config like this : "container_commands:
    01_chmod_mysql:
        command: chmod -R 755 /var/app/staging/Database/
    02_chmod_app_webapp:
        command: chmod -R 755 /var/app/staging/WebApp/
    03_chmod_app_webapi:
        command: chmod -R 755 /var/app/staging/WebAPI/"